# How can I add a property with a dot in the name to an existing CanJS can.Map?

Tags: javascript, canjs

Say I have an existing `can.Map` called `someMap` and I need to add a new property named `some.data` that will contain a `string`.

In vanilla JS, you can do `someMap["some.data"] = "someString" \\ Object {some.data: "someString"}`

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with a `can.Map` unless I do something like extract the `someMap.attr()` and store that in a `var`, then add the property to that `var` like above, then do `someMap.attr(someObjVar)`, but this fires no change event which is needed here.

Is there a way to do this? Renaming the property is not an option :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. URL encode it then decode it on the way out.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape keys of `can.Map`:

```
var a = {};
a['test.key'] = 'value';
var map = new can.Map(a);
map.attr('test\.key'); // "value"
```